# How to extract character and number from alphanumeric value using php

Tags: php

I want to extract character and number from a alphanumeric value

For example `300G` I want extract `300` and `G` as different values
500M : want to 500 and M 
Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code should do the trick.

```
$str = '300G';

preg_match("/(\d+)(.)/", $str, $matches);

$number = $matches[1];
$character = $matches[2];

echo $number; // 300
echo $character; // G
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with [`preg_match`](http://php.net/preg_match):

```
$input = '300G';
preg_match('/(\d+)(\w)/', $input, $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

Output:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => string '300G' (length=4)
  1 => string '300' (length=3)
  2 => string 'G' (length=1)
```

And extra:

```
list(, $digits, $letter) = $matches;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$input = '300G';
$number = substr($input, 0, -1);
$letter = substr($input, -1);
```

Answer (score 0):

use a regular expression

```
   $regexp = "/([0-9]+)([A-Z]+)/";
   $string = "300G";

   preg_match($regexp, $string, $matches);

   print_r($matches);
```

`$matches[1] = 300`
`$matches[2] = G`

Answer (score 0):

```
$pattern = '#([a-z]+)([\d]+)#i';
if (preg_match($pattern, $str, $matches)){
    $letters = $matches[1];
    $numbers = $matches[2];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<?php
    $input = '300G';
    preg_match('/(\d+)(\w)/', $input, $matches);
    var_dump($matches);
?>
```